# Can plans be dicey

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

So, I have heard my parents and a bunch of other people say "My plans are dicey".

I always assumed that it means, plans being fluid and not concrete.

Today someone pointed out that dicey means unpredictable and dangerous.

Can someone confirm if the way I use the word "dicey" is correct.

Comment: What does a dictionary tell you?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dicey

Comment: I haven't owned or looked at a dictionary in ages! But apparently, that guy is quoting Google search result or where ever Google picks up word  definitions from.

Comment: @Aditya: Most reputable dictionaries have online versions for free, although they are not always as complete as the print versions. ELL expects askers to use a dictionary routinely as necessary to discover basic word meanings.

Comment: When the situation, whatever it is, is **dicey**, the situation has a degree of unpredictability, such that things can go wrong.  So there's unpredictability with risk.  *At this point along the river, things get really dicey.  You will have to be very careful, as the rapids go from Class 3 to Class 5*. Or   *That itinerary is rather dicey. You have only twelve minutes to make a connecting flight in Chicago.*

Answer (score 1):

Dicey definitely means chancy and unpredictable, it comes from the idea of rolling dice, an inherently unpredictable action.

Your previous definition works in a way, since fluid plans by nature are able to react to uncertainty, but it is not the same thing.

If you mean your plans flexible or subject to change, fluid is a much better word.